# Given that f(n)= n.f(n-1)+ 2(n+1)! and given that f(0)=1, we can write the solution as:

Tags: functions

Given that f(n)= n.f(n-1)+ 2(n+1)! and given that f(0)=1, we can write the solution as:

Select one:

a. f(n)= n!(n(n+2) + 1)

b. f(n)=n!(n(n+3)/2 + 1)

c. f(n)= n!(n(n+3)+1)

d. f(n)= n(n+3) + 1

So I am used to finding recurrence equations from questions such as f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2). However when I look at this question it puts me off a little because the layout is awkward.

Why do we need f(0) = 1 in the question? it seems like they express f(n) in terms of only n.

I also find it a little odd, because when I put f(0) back into the equation f(n)= n.f(n-1)+ 2(n+1)! I get,  f(0) = 0.f(-1) + 2(1)! = 2 , which clearly is not the case, as f(0) = 1. Am I doing something wrong?

How would do I express f(n) = n.f(n-1) + 2(n+1)! in terms of only n?

Comment: is that $2(n+1)!, (2n+1)!$ or $(2n+2)!$?

Comment: ..and yeah, next time, pls use Latex

Answer (score 2):

Let $f(n)=g(n)\cdot n!$

$n=0\implies\cdots g(0)=1$

$g(n)\cdot n!=n g(n-1)\cdot (n-1)!+2(n+1)!$

$\iff g(n)=g(n-1)+2(n+1)$

Let $g(n)=h(n)+an^2+bn+c\  \ \ \  (1)$

$1=g(0)=h(0)+c\iff h(0)=1-c$

$\implies h(n)+an^2+bn+c=h(n-1)+a(n-1)^2+b(n-1)+c+2(n+1)$

$\iff h(n)=h(n-1)+a-b+2+2n(1-a)$

Set $1-a=0\iff a=1,a-b+2=0\iff b=a+2=3$

to get $h(n)=h(n-1)=\cdots=h(0)=1-c$

From $(1),g(n)=1-c+(1)n^2+(3)n+c=n^2+3n+1$

Comment: This does seem quite hard to follow, but I guess the general plan was to simplify the equation by getting rid of ! and then  I don't understand what goes on after that. I can however see that you managed to calculate that g(n) = n^2 + 3n + 1 which results in f(n) = n!(n^2 + 3n + 1), is there a particular theorem you are using that I can read up on?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean $2(n+1)!$, if you divide LHS and RHS through $n!$, then set $b(n) = \frac{f(n)}{n!}$, you get 
$$
b(n) = b(n-1) + 2(n+1)
$$
and you life becomes much easier!

Comment: So once this problem is simplified, how would I go about generating a recurrence equation? I'm usually used to solving the equation of the form f(n) = f(n-1) + f(n-2)

Comment: You have recurrence for $b_n$. Solve it, the plug in $f_n$ back.

Comment: How would I solve it?

n^2 = n + 2 ? then find values of n etc?

Comment: 1)express bn as a function of n only 2) plug in back fn

Comment: my problem is how do I express b(n) as a function of n?

Answer (score 0):

Solving such a multiple choice problem does *not* require solving the recurrence. More simply, it requires only computing enough initial values to exclude the nonsolutions. Here the value of $\,f(1)\,$ excludes all but $2$ choices and the value of $f(2)$ narrows it down to a unique candidate. This can be done in a minute or two of mental arithmetic.

You need the value of $f(0)$ because this is the base case of the recursive definition of $\,f(n).\,$ From that, using the recurrence, you can (uniquely) calculate the value of $\,f(n)\,$ for all positive integers.