# Recursive equation with limit

Tags: combinatorics, limits, discrete-mathematics, recursion

Find $\alpha, \beta, \gamma$ for recursive equation:

$$ \alpha a_{n+3}-3a_{n+1}+\beta a_n = 18n$$  $$a_0=0,a_1=\gamma, a_2=3 $$

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{3a_n+(-2)^{n}}{n^3}=3$$

Hey guys,

normally I know my way around recursive equations, but when it comes to exercise with limits like this one I don't know how to use the information from the limit condition. I looked in to answers and found out, that first you have to figure out that $a_n$ is formed like $n^3-\frac{1}{3}(-2)^n+ ...$

How can I come to this and move on from there?

My attempt was something like this:
$$\frac{3a_n+(-2)^{n}}{n^3}=3/*n^3$$
$$3a_n+(-2)^{n}=3n^3/-(-2)^{n}$$
$$3a_n=3n^3-(-2)^{n}/*\frac{1}{3}$$
$$a_n=n^3-\frac{1}{3}(-2)^{n}$$

but I don't know if this is correct and which parts are missing in $+...$ Please help

Comment: One way: $a_m=b_m+a+bm+cm^2+dm^3$

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1192253/find-a-n-if-a-n-is-a-sequence-such-that-a-1-1-and-frac1a/1192254#1192254 OR http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199375/closed-form-of-recurrence-equation/1199383#1199383 OR http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1193846/given-that-fn-n-fn-1-2n1-and-given-that-f0-1-we-can-write-the-solut/1193851#1193851

Comment: Are you certain $\alpha~a_{n+3}$ isn't a typo, rather $\alpha~a_{n+2}$ ?

Comment: I'm certain, it says $\alpha a_{n+3}$

Answer (score 2):

First, convert the recursion to a linear recursion:

$$\alpha~a_{n+3}-3~a_{n+1}+\beta~ a_{n} = 18~n \tag{1}$$
$$\alpha~a_{n+4}-3~a_{n+2}+\beta~ a_{n+1} = 18~n +18 \tag{2}$$
$$\alpha~a_{n+5}-3~a_{n+3}+\beta~ a_{n+2} = 18~n + 36\tag{3}$$

Eliminate the nonlinear terms with linear algebra:

$$a_{n+5} = 2~a_{n+4} + 
\left(\frac{3}{\alpha} - 1\right)~a_{n+3} +
\left(-\frac{\beta}{\alpha} - \frac{6}{\alpha}\right)~a_{n+2} +
\left(\frac{2\beta}{\alpha} + \frac{3}{\alpha}\right)~a_{n+1} -
\left(\frac{\beta}{\alpha} \right )~a_{n} \tag{4}$$

This is a linear recursion represented by the matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix} a_{n+4} \\ a_{n+3} \\ a_{n+2} \\ a_{n+1} \\ a_{n+0} \end{bmatrix} = 
\underbrace{\begin{bmatrix}
2 & 
\frac{3}{\alpha} - 1 &
-\frac{\beta}{\alpha} - \frac{6}{\alpha} &
\frac{2\beta}{\alpha} + \frac{3}{\alpha} &
-\frac{\beta}{\alpha} \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{bmatrix}^n}_M
\begin{bmatrix}a_{4} \\ a_{3} \\ a_{2} \\ a_{1} \\ a_{0}\end{bmatrix}
\tag{5}$$

For the recurrence to have a cubic $k^nn^3$ and an exponential $r^n$ term, then Jordan form of the matrix must contain subblocks:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
k & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & k & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & k & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & k \\
\end{bmatrix} \text{ and } \begin{bmatrix} r \end{bmatrix}$$

Since the matrix is 5 by 5, with $k = 1$ and $r = -2$ the Jordan form can only be:

$${\rm Jordan}(M) = 
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -2
\end{bmatrix}$$

So $M$ has an eigenvalue $1$ with multiplicity $4$ and eigenvalue $-2$ with multiplicity $1$.  Expanding $\det (\lambda I - M) = 0$  you get:

$$\begin{cases}\lambda^5
 - 2~\lambda^4
 - \left(\frac 3{\alpha} - 1\right)~\lambda^3
 + \frac{\beta+6}{~\alpha}~\lambda^2
 - \frac{2~\beta+3}{\alpha}\lambda + \frac \beta{\alpha} = 0 \\
(\lambda - 1)^4(\lambda + 2) = 0
\end{cases}$$

Solving gives $~\alpha=1$, $\beta=2$.

Comment: Thanks, but is there any other way?

Comment: There's probably a way to rewrite the limit as $$G(j, k) ~~:~~ \lim_{n \to \infty} k~a_{n+j} - \frac{1}{3} (-2)^{n+j} - (n+j)^3 + f(n) = 0$$ where $f(n)$ is some function asymptotically less than $n^3$.   Add up $G(3, \alpha) + G(1, -3) + G(0, \beta)$ and substitute the original recursion to eliminate the $a$ terms and equate coefficients of the $n$ terms to zero to make the limit exist and it might work.  Maybe.  Maybe not.  I think the approach in the answer is easier and more confident.

Comment: One thing you have to somehow realize is that because the lineared equation is only 6 terms, it can't contain an exponential term, and cubic, and another function of $n$.  There just aren't enough eigenvalues to make it happen.  I don't think there is an "ansatz and check" way to epiphany that.